# StackView not appearing correct on all screen sizes

Tags: swift, autolayout, uistackview

I have a ViewController that contains a Stack View. In this Stack View there are 3 more Stack Views. The first contains 3 labels, the second contains more Stack Views with buttons and labels, and the third contains 2 buttons and a label. And at the bottom, there is a button. The layout is fine on screen sizes from 4,7" and bigger. But when the screen size is smaller, it cuts out the top Stack View. I have tried to set constraints on leading, trailing, top and bottom in different variations (with and without top and bottom constraints) But I can't make it work properly. I have attached screenshots of the different screen types.

[image: Screen size 4,7"]

[image: Screen size 4"]

EDIT* Depending on the selection from the previous `ViewController`, the middle `Stack View`(the one with the check boxes) can be `isHidden` When its hidden, the view is correct.

Comment: Have you tried running it in different simulator or devices?

Comment: Yes. I forgot to mention that one of the `Stack View` can be hidden. See edited post.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you don't set height on `UIStackView`. They are dependent on it's content. This will cause your stackview to get out of the screen height. Have you used the view hierarchy? If you want to cover the small sized phones you could put your main stackView inside a scrollView to still be able to see all content.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit difficult to diagnose what's happening without seeing the constraints you apply to the views, however I'll recommend you some things that may help:

- Set the space between views using size classes so you can set the right one depending on the screen size and avoid the overlap with the below views.

[image]

- In case you are doing it, don't set a height constraint for any stackView.
- To align the top `StackView` I would use not only a top constraint to the top bar (of type greater than or equal) but also a vertical center constraint with a right multiplier (with a high priority). In this way you ensure the top stack view is aligned vertically in proportion to the screen size and with the top constraint you ensure the stackView doesn't hide below the top bar.
- Make sure you are hiding the right stackView.